# IE JS-error when closing a Fancybox-iframe containing a YouTube movie

Tags: javascript, debugging, iframe, youtube, fancybox

The following error can even be found the FancyApps page itself. Go to http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ in Internet Explorer 9 for example. Go to Internet Options > Advanced > Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer). Click on the YouTube (iframe)-link and close the movie. You'll see the following error appear onscreen:

Line: 1
Error: '_*flash*_removeCallback' is undefined

Any idea on how this error can be avoided? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different implementation of the functionality. I have this error when stopping a YouTube video by removing the iframe html. Instead, just wrap the iframe into a div and then just refresh the src. If you want to remove the video then just hide it.

Instead of

```
$('#youTube').html("");
```

I use

```
$('#youTube iframe').attr('src', $('#youTube iframe').attr('src'));
$('#youTube').hide();
```

On

```
<div id='youTube'>
<iframe width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.